# C# REST API Authenticate with Bearer Token

Tags: c#, rest, api, authentication, bearer-token

Trying to write a tool which downloads a .zip file from a server via REST API.
It works without any problems with SOAP-UI but my tool doesn't want to download any files.

Always getting this error:

> Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.

My POST-Requests work fine but GET-Requests make problems. I Think there is a problem with my Webrequest-Header.

The authentication has to look like this:

> Bearer "Access Token"

Here is my code:

```
class RestProvider
{
    protected string method;
    protected string endpoint;
    protected string resource;
    protected string parameters;


    public RestProvider(string method, string endpoint, string resource, string parameters)
    {
        this.method = method;
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }


    public string GetResponse()
    {
        string resultString = string.Empty;
        ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] paramData = enc.GetBytes(parameters);

        if (this.method == "post")
        {
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(this.endpoint + this.resource);
                request.Method = this.method;
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = paramData.Length;

                Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                stream.Write(paramData, 0, paramData.Length);
                stream.Close();

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                stream = response.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                resultString = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
                stream.Close();
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                resultString = "{\"errorMessages\":[\"" + ex.Message.ToString() + "\"],\"errors\":{}}";
            }
        }

        else if(this.method == "get")
        {
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(this.endpoint + this.resource);
                request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(this.parameters));
                request.Method = this.method;
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = paramData.Length;

                Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                stream.Write(paramData, 0, paramData.Length);
                stream.Close();

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                stream = response.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                resultString = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
                stream.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                resultString = "{\"errorMessages\":[\"" + ex.Message.ToString() + "\"],\"errors\":{}}";
            }
        }

        return resultString;       
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are writing parameters data in request stream in get method. That is not allowed. When making request with get verb request body is not allowed. You need to send the parameters values by appending them in url as querystring in get request.

Comment: Looks like problem with the "get" branch, where you are trying to write paramData in the stream. Remove that part from "get"

Comment: @ASpirin I removed it but it still doesnt work.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya how do i do this?